Объединение файлов в формате dbf python
Код должен объединять все файлы находящиеся в папке, в один общий новый файл формата dbf. Но выполняется запись только первого файла в итоговый. Не могу понять в чем ошибка
import os
import glob
import shutil

folder_path = r'C:\Users\akaun\OneDrive\Desktop\dbf_files'
output_file = r"C:\Users\akaun\OneDrive\Desktop\dbf_files\Name4.dbf"

with open(output_file, 'wb') as wfd:

    for filename in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.dbf'))):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fd:  
            shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd, 1024*1024*10) 


Запустите с отладкой, и посмотрите, меняется ли filename. Или просто print(filename) в цикле делайте. Из очевидных проблем вижу только, что вы пишете в файл в той же папке, откуда файлы читаете. Если файл Name4.dfb уже существовал до запуска программы (например, вы запускаете не первый раз), то будет попытка одновременного чтения и записи в него, нужно добавить проверку, что это не один и тот же файл.

А ещё мне кажется, что вы просто пытаетесь конкатенировать все файлы... не, в DBF так, конечно, можно, но вместо данных из исходных таблиц получится фарш.

DBF - формат базы данных, а не текстовый. Наиболее распространённая субд, использовавшая этот формат в 90-2000-хх годах, FoxPro. Даже внутри этой среды нельзя просто так брать и соединять - у баз должны быть одинаковые структуры и результаты слияния тоже должны быть понятны до того. Я работаю с dbf до сих пор, уже 30 лет. Нет, так не будет.

У меня прямо сейчас есть работающая база данных, использующая старую базу данных DBF. В среде FoxPro написан скрипт, который экспортирует данные в CSV, а в Питоне данные из CSV импортируются в базу данных sqlite3. Можно конечно и в CSV оставаться, но это неудобно и много писанины бестолковой, особенно есть учесть, что в таблице 3,2 млн. записей.

Я не пользовался сам этим, поскольку мне написать скрипт на FoxPro проще, но говорят, что есть такие модули: 1) simpledbf: Этот модуль позволяет конвертировать файлы .dbf в .csv, а также в другие форматы, такие как Pandas DataFrames, SQL таблицы и HDF5 таблицы. 2) dbfread: Этот модуль позволяет читать файлы .dbf и конвертировать их в .csv. Сшивать csv с одинаковой структурой уже можно и в Питоне.

А если наоборот, надо создавать файл dbf из других, то утилиту лучше писать на Visual FoxPro. И понимать, что при этом происходит. Там можно из скрипта сделать .exe, но всё равно на машине клиента должна быть проинсталлирована поддержка работы баз данных Visual FoxPro. Эту программу тоже нужно уметь создать. Попытки импорта баз данных с помощью ODBC на порядок сложнее. Visual FoxPro - официально похоронен. В современных версиях ОС вся эта кухня тупо не работает. Есть ещё модули: dbfpy и dbf, которые якобы могут оперировать с базами .dbf без участия FoxPro, но я лично не проверял это.
